# n number of LIKE in a SQL statement

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I have a table `list` with a list of records like

```
list_Name
A1
A2
A3
A4
```

Another table `dest` contains a column having a long string

```
ID  String
1   A1 This is line 1 A2
2   A3 Line number 2
3   A5 Line 3
```

Using values in `list` table, I want to find a record from `dest` table

What I know is fetching them one by one. Example-

```
SELECT * FROM dest WHERE string LIKE '%A1%' OR string LIKE '%A2%'
```

But how I can I use `LIKE` for every value in `list` table?

`list` table can have n number of records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JOIN/EXISTS` to do check every value in `LIST` table.

I usually prefer `EXISTS` for checking the existence.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dest d 
WHERE exists (select 1 from list l where d.string LIKE '%'+list_Name+'%')
```

To resolve Collation conflict we can use explicit collation

```
SELECT * 
FROM   dest d 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   list l 
               WHERE  d.string COLLATE database_default LIKE 
                      '%' + list_name + '%' COLLATE database_default)
```

Comment: Well, I'm using this in a trigger. Not sure if trigger worked. After inserting record, I'm getting error `Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AI" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the like operation.`

Comment: @kamalpreet - It says `string` and `list_Name` has two different `collation`. We can solve this by using explicit collation

Comment: In my case, `string` value is very long text. In trigger when a match is found, It takes about 15 sec to process that query. Any idea to optimize it?

Comment: @kamalpreet You can create a `full text index`. Which is the correct implementation in your case. But it is a different question altogether